# Why does VS2017 say await is an unknown keyword?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, task-parallel-library

```
    internal /*async*/ void RunAsync()
    {
        var tasks = ...;
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
```

In the above example, the IDE informs me "the ''await operator can only be used within an async method". It offers me fixes to make my method signature `async void` or `async Task`

```
    internal /*async*/ void RunAsync()
    {
        var tasks = ...;
        var t = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        await t;
    }
```

In the second example, it gives the error "the type or namespace await cannot be found"... `await` is not color-coded as a language keyword and the IDE offers me no automatic fixes.

Is this a VS bug?

Comment: As an aside, you really should avoid `async void`. Use `async Task` instead.

Comment: When you say it isn't valid what exactly do you mean? Are you getting a compilation error?

Comment: I reject your premise, you absolutely can `await` `t` here.

Comment: @DavidG you are right - I _was_ getting a compiler error "the type or namespace await can not be found". But only when my method signature was missing `async`. Whereas in my first example, omitting the method modifier gives me a proper error and suggests the fix!

Comment: I will rewrite ...

Comment: What happens when you have `internal async Task` signature? Maybe you have to target newer version of .NET in project?

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Obviously there is no problem if you uncomment `async`.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn as GSerg says. I left it commented to show I know I need it, but demonstrate the issue caused.

Comment: Apparently it's down to whether the parser can tell an await call apart from a function call. In the first method, you can get the second's method behaviour by using `await (Task.WhenAll(tasks));` (note the parentheses). `await (t)` in the second also changes the diagnostics.

Comment: This just feels like a compiler oddity. Not great, but if you want to open an issue on GitHub, they might look at it.

Comment: It seems that you want to use task.whenall. You can refer to MSDN doc [Task.WhenAll Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.8) to know it.

Answer (score 2):

The code is invalid C# code in both cases. So the compiler/IDE has to do its best to figure out what you're *trying* to do and give you an appropriate error message.

> In the above example, the IDE informs me "the ''await operator can only be used within an async method". It offers me fixes to make my method signature async void or async Task

VS is parsing the code and is pretty sure that the `await` here is intended to be the `await` operator. The code isn't valid C#, but that's what it looks like you're trying to do. So it gives you a helpful suggestion that you have to have the `async` keyword to make `await` a keyword.

> In the second example, it gives the error "the type or namespace await cannot be found"... await is not color-coded as a language keyword and the IDE offers me no automatic fixes.

VS is parsing the code and is not sure whether the `await` here is an `await` operator or a type. `await t;` looks a lot like `int t;` to the compiler.

> Is this a VS bug?

It's not a bug, since the code is invalid C# to begin with. But you could ask for a better error message in the second case, and the C# compiler team may or may not decide it's worth doing that instead of working on other features.

For context, note that [`await` is a *contextual* keyword](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2011/09/async-ctp-why-do-keywords-work-that-way.html). It's only a keyword if the `async` keyword is present. `await` is *not* always a keyword, and it would be a bug if VS were to always treat it as a keyword. Specifically, in both the code examples here, `await` is not a keyword. VS goes out of its way to do extra fallback parsing in the first example to detect a common scenario where the developer *intended* to use the `await` keyword.

Comment: *It's only a keyword if the `async` keyword is present.... it would be a bug if VS were to always treat it as a keyword* - well, in the first method the `await` is highlighted in blue as a keyword, even given the lack of `async`. Then it should be a bug according to what you're saying.

Comment: @GSerg: The compiler is guessing that the user's intent is to use `await` as a keyword. Since the code is invalid, what the user's intent is is always a guess, and the compiler just does the best it can. There's no bug as long as the code is invalid; the compiler could just say "invalid C# file" for every single error if it wanted to.